# Jasig-CAS single sign out with one link

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-webflow, cas

Based on cas tutorial, in order to single sign out, the client should click on

> /j_spring_security_logout

and on logout success page click on

> /j_spring_cas_security_logout

to quit cas server and close session on that.
But what if I want to get out of client app and server both simultaneously with single link?

Answer (score 1):

You can always force an HTTP redirect to /j_spring_cas_security_logout, without user interaction, on the second page.

Comment: I did it, but the application still remains logged in.

Comment: I'm not very proud of my answer (there might be a cleaner solution)... Anyway, have you tried different redirection methods? (http header, html "meta" tag, javascript redirection, returning the view with the "redirect:/j_spring_cas_security_logout" name)...